# integral of absolute value of a function is zero implies the set of nonzero's is of volume zero

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function over a closed rectangle $Q\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define $Z=\{x\in Q|f(x)\neq 0\}$.

**Prove** that if $\int_Q|f|=0$, then $vol(Z)=0$.

I tried: $0=\int_Q|f|=\int_Z|f|+\int_{Q\setminus Z}|f|=\int_Z|f|+0=\int_Z|f|$.

Comment: What is a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Say $Q=[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_n,b_n]$ @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z_n=\left\{x\in Q\,\middle|\,\bigl|f(x)\bigr|\geqslant\frac1n\right\}$. Then $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}Z_n=Z$ and$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\int_{Z_n}|f|\leqslant\int_Q|f|=0,$$and therefore $(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):\int_{Z_n}|f|=0$. But$$0=\int_{Z_n}|f|\geqslant\frac{\operatorname{vol}(Z_n)}n\geqslant0.$$So, $\operatorname{vol}(Z_n)=0$ and therefore$$\operatorname{vol}(Z)=\operatorname{vol}\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}Z_n\right)\leqslant\sum_{n=1}^\infty\operatorname{vol}(Z_n)=0.$$

Comment: Does here _vol_ mean jordan measure ?

Comment: I assumed that the OP meant Lebesgue measure.